# Select CASE / CASE over range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with 36K lines. Each of the 36K lines will be matched to one of about 350 numbers. When that number is matched, I will have text and colons input into another column on the same row as the matching number. The questions I have are:

1. How can I have the macro run over a range (Example: T2:T36000) and return a value for each row?
2. Can I do this by column instead of the row range. (Example: Column called Category, instead of T2:T36000). The reason for this is that the number of rows in each column will be changing.

This works for one row at a time, but I don't want to have to do this for each row. I realize I will have to put values for each of the 350 different numbers.

```
Sub CategoryChanger()
Select Case Range("AS2").Value
  Case 1492
   Range("T2") = "IT DOES NOT WORKS"
  Case 1491
   Range("T2") = "IT WORKS"
End Select
End Sub
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Look in to how to use a `For Each ... Next` statement. This will allow you to iterate over a range of cells in a column or row, for example.  You can then use some other methods like `Offset` to print the value to adjacent cells.

Comment: Here is a full list of [vba statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278949(v=office.14).aspx) with documentation on each.

Answer (score 2):

Basic loop iteration using `For Each ... Next` statement:

```
Sub CategoryChanger()

Dim rng as Range
Dim r as Range
Dim result as String

'## Define a range to represent the cells over which you would like to iterate:
'## Modify as needed...

Set rng = Range("AS2:AS100") 
'## Iterate each cell in the Range defined "rng"
For Each r in rng.Cells
    Select Case r.Value
      Case 1492
          result = "IT DOES NOT WORKS"
      Case 1491
          result = "IT WORKS"
    End Select

    '## Print result in the cell 10 columns to right
    '## Modify as needed
    r.Offset(0, 10).Value = result
Next
End Sub
```

With 350+ values to check against 30,000 rows of data, you may be better served to index this as a table on another (hidden) worksheet and use the `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` to do the lookup, rather than forcing through a Case switch like this.

In that case you would omit the `Select Case` block altogether, and simply do like so (assuming you add a worksheet named "Lookup" and put your lookup table in range A1:B350):

```
Sub CategoryChanger()

Dim rng as Range
Dim r as Range
Dim result as String

'## Define a range to represent the cells over which you would like to iterate:
'## Modify as needed...

Set rng = Range("AS2:AS100") 
'## Iterate each cell in the Range defined "rng"
For Each r in rng.Cells
    On Error Resume Next
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(r.Value, Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A1:B350"), 2, False)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then result = "NOT FOUND!"
    On Error GoTo 0
    '## Print result in the cell 10 columns to right
    '## Modify as needed
    rng.Offset(0, 10).Value = result

    'Clear out the "result" value for the next iteration:
    result = vbNullstring
Next



End Sub
```

I am not sure which would be optimized for this use.

Comment: see revised answer, you simply need to reassign the value of `result` at the end of (or at the beginning of) each iteration. I do it here right before the `Next` statement, just set it to a blank value.